# Full Java Config of app-context.xml including for example jdbc and tx directives

Tags: java, spring, spring-4

I am using spring 4.2.1 and wanted to move away from xml configs in all their flavours. In this case I want to get rid of my app-config.xml but am finding it hard to find information about this when it comes to all but the most trivial entries (@Configuration and @Bean). My old xml config class has entries like:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="de.dahi.resourcecal.repos"/>
```

How can I do those in java config? I found an old spring-javaconfig from 2008 and also a comment from the old project lead that it had been merged into core and didn't apply any more. But the question is how do I do things like that in java now?
I found the following blog entry (http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/spring-4-xml-to-annotation-configuration.html) for the same with spring-security and also .config packages in the respective spring jars (org.springframework.transaction.config) but no info on how to use anything in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the **`2.1.2 Annotation based configuration`** section in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html). It has an example of annotation-based configuration for the tags you include in your question. You can set the `basePackage` for the jpa repository using the `value` property of the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation - see the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html).

The EmbeddedDataBaseBuilder can handle H2 as well, for example:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
  EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
  return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks leeor. Searching the docs is confusing with the number of different spring versions and all the outdated information about spring-javaconfig and I overlooked the page you posted.  But when it exists it is of course the right source. I think a good approach also is that what I mentioned: add the spring jar that you are looking to config using java annotation based config. Search for the .config package and see which of the classes there are annotations and how they match up with the xsd which is usually to be found in the same directory.